# Cannot insert LayoutNode@cc72396 children, because it already has a parent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is a slight variation from the official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/LookaheadScope), of the `LookaheadScope`.

This is the branch, the [main](https://github.com/idiotleon/DemoLookaheadLayout) branch, which always works well, while the [develop](https://github.com/idiotleon/DemoLookaheadLayout/tree/develop) branch, with limited changes, causes an exception thrown.

The limited changes mainly are about layout.

To highlight:

in the main branch, which always works well,

```kotlin
if (isInColumn) {
    Column {
        item0()
        item1()
        item2()
        item3()
    }
} else {
    Row {
        item0()
        item1()
        item2()
        item3()
    }
}
```

with a slightly different layout:
(the idea is just to try to introduce more complex layouts)

```kotlin
if (isInColumn) {
    Column {
        item0()
        item1()
        Row {
            item2()
            item3()
        }
    }
} else {
    Row {
        Column {
            item0()
            item1()
        }
        item2()
        item3()
    }
}
```

The first click always works, however, the 2nd click always crashes.

The full exception thrown:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.idiotleon.demo.demolookaheadapplication, PID: 24551
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot insert LayoutNode@cc72396 children: 0 measurePolicy: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$EmptyBoxMeasurePolicy$1@5465a19 because it already has a parent. This tree: |-LayoutNode@5d08563 children: 1 measurePolicy: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1@6be2ade
|-LayoutNode@01962b1 children: 0 measurePolicy: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$EmptyBoxMeasurePolicy$1@5465a19 Other tree: |-LayoutNode@68fe1f5 children: 1 measurePolicy: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1@6be2ade
|-LayoutNode@cc72396 children: 0 measurePolicy: androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$EmptyBoxMeasurePolicy$1@5465a19
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.insertAt$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:246)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.UiApplier.insertBottomUp(UiApplier.android.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.UiApplier.insertBottomUp(UiApplier.android.kt:21)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$insertMovableContentGuarded$1$1$3.invoke(Composer.kt:3102)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$insertMovableContentGuarded$1$1$3.invoke(Composer.kt:3097)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked(Composition.kt:810)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyLateChanges(Composition.kt:852)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:607)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:510)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1410)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1420)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1047)
at android.view.ChoreographerExtImpl.checkScrollOptSceneEnable(ChoreographerExtImpl.java:442)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:918)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1395)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8416)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@69eb7b6, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@a51dcb7, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@2a4ec24, AndroidUiDispatcher@803b38d]
```

What is this exception about? Looks like the new layout node cannot be removed at first and thus cannot be inserted.

How to debug and resolve this, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve by defining a child row inside a row , but the issue comes from the fact that compose has no idea how to measure or balance between the child row layout and the other children of your parent row layout ( the one after the else).

i tested your code on my machine and something like this solves the crash issues . In this code there's two row child layout and compose can automatically solve the measurement issues between them

```
else {
            Row {
                Row {
                    item0()
                    item1()
                }
                Row() {
                    item2()
                    item3()
                }
            }
        }
```

Now if you're wondering why this causes no similar problems :

```
if (isInColumn) {
    Column {
        item0()
        item1()
        Row {
            item2()
            item3()
        }
    }
}
```

it's because the other children(of the column) are defined before the other child layout , so compose will calculate their measurements first then calculate the child-layout measurements after with no issues

alternatively something like this would also fix your code

```
     else {
            Row() {
                    item0()
                    item1()
                Row() {
                    item2()
                    item3()
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm not the best explainer around but I hope this made some sense.

Edit 1: more or less same solution just wrap item2() and item3() with a row and you'll have no issues

```
if (isInColumn) {
            Column {
                item0()
                item1()
                Row {
                    item2()
                    item3()
                }
            }
        } else {
            Row() {
                Column{
                    item0()
                    item1()
                }

                Row() {
                    item2()
                    item3()
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the `Row` with `Column`, if this helps :). The idea is just to try to introduce more complicated layouts. Thanks for your quick response. I have not digested your answer yet. Will make it ASAP.

Comment: no worries , edited my answer and tested it again with no crashes . Just wrap the item2 and item3 with a row to avoid the issue.